# Beginning PHP for someone interested in Security

Tags: php

I'd like to learn PHP specifically for dealing with security vulnerabilities/exploits.

Could someone recommend a book?

I don't know if I need to learn HTML/CSS/XML/XHTML etc, do I have to learn those too? I don't really plan on designing websites, could anyone help me with this? :P

Comment: Do you want to learn about security in web applications in general or about security in PHP applications in particular?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at "Essential PHP Security" by Chris Shiflett (http://phpsecurity.org/). I found it very useful when learning PHP.

Comment: Does that talk about the PHP basics?

I want to learn the core fundamentals, but I'm not sure about HTML/CSS, is there a book that covers it all?

Comment: As far as I remember this book assumes as basic knowledge of PHP - but as others have pointed out it's probably worth reading a book about PHP basics, then reading this book (as introductory PHP books do not cover security in any detail)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question, although you don't have to be a HTML/CSS/XML/XHTML  Guru, knowing the fundamentals is absolutely important. I believe, no developer will be asked to concentrate and code 100% on the server side logic alone, eg if you want to create AJAX web application the knowledge of XHTML and JavaScript becomes necessary. Knowing XML will also be of prime importance when dealing with data over the internet through web services.

So yes knowing a little HTML/CSS/XML/XHTML is absa-freaking-loutely important.

Comment: Hi @MaXX are you a PHP beginner or an expert? i ask this because if you're a beginner, the books for beginners will not cover enough about security, they amy brush up on a few things but not advanced topics like XSS, CSRF attcks etc.

Whereas if you are an expert there a number of books available in amazon, you judge the books by reading the reviews, and choosing the right. Sorry that i did'nt point to a specific one never having learned PHP myself :)

Comment: I'm a beginner, I'm actually looking for a beginner book.

Answer (score 0):

**#1 rule, do not trust *anything* coming from the user.**

Take a look at the [Zend PHP 5 Certification Study Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0973862149).  It covers everything from PHP basics, through MySQL, and even into advanced OOP Classes.  It even has a chapter on PHP Security.  I'm currently using this for teaching my graduate-level PHP class.